# Remove an array from an Array if a certain value exists in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to remove an entire array if within my data if it contains a certain value.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

```
data = [['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'],
['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']]


var del_value = 'J-001';

function remove_from_list(list) {
    for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
        for( var j =0; j < Object.keys(list[i]).length.length; j++) {
            if(del_value == list[i][j]) {
                list.splice(list[i], 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

actual output

```js
data = 
[['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'],
['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']]
```

desired result -- to remove all arrays that have the value `'J-001'`

```js
data = 
[['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'],
['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001']]
```

Comment: @HassanImam yeah, it would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const data = [['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'],
['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']];

const input = "J-001";


// Approach 
// Filter element (use filter) who has not given input (use not includes for this)
const result = data.filter(dat => !dat.includes(input));

console.log(result);
```

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#filter` and `array#includes` to filter based on array not including `J-001`.

```js
const data = [['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'], ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'], ['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'], ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']],
      result = data.filter(arr => !arr.includes('J-001'));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If the position of the element is fixed to be third. Then you can use
directly compare the value at that index.

```js
const data = [['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'], ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'], ['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'], ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']],
      result = data.filter(arr => arr[3] !== 'J-001');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach using `Array.filter()` and `Array.find()`.

```js
data = [['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman','J-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','K-001'],
['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens','Z-001'],
['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon','J-001']];

function removeFromList(list, delValue) {
  return list.filter(arr => !arr.find(value => value === delValue));
}

console.log(removeFromList(data, 'J-001'));
```